# Is there a possibility to send Data via Port Nodes?

Tags: node-editor

With Port Nodes I mean Nodes which have Sender and a Receiver where no cables / connections are needed for. Those Port Nodes should be used to declutter complex Nodes.

Something like this:

[image]

Comment: isn't this exactly what the nodes-groups are for?

Comment: Not possible atm but it's in debate https://devtalk.blender.org/t/portal-links-exploration/21306

Comment: @Chris Yes true, Node Groups declutter as well but I was looking for something that can even transport data inside Groups as well.

Comment: @Gorgious Thanks! Is there a way to create own Nodes via C++ ?

Comment: The only way at the moment to create new nodes in C++ is to download the blender source, add your node code, and build a new version of Blender.  The good news is that there is a lot of support information available for doing this. The bad news is that it's time consuming.

Comment: Thanks @Marty !

Answer (score 0):

Could implement a first Prototype.

[image]

[image]

Noted it here https://hackmd.io/t8grsfwpTpubvsSYnrCPMg?view